# sorting multiple array with multiple criteria

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have this array:

```
array(
        '200' => array (
            "desc" => "sub array",
            "_id" => 200,
            "_parent" => 163,
            "_level" => 2,
            "_is_leaf" => false
        ),

        '165' => array (
            "desc" => "sub array from 200",
            "_id" => 165,
            "_parent" => 200,
            "_level" => 3,
            "_is_leaf" => true
        ),


        '167' => array (
            "desc" => "sub array from 172",
            "_id" => 167,
            "_parent" => 172,
            "_level" => 3,
            "_is_leaf" => true
        ),

        '163' => array (
            "desc" => "master array",
            "_id" => 163,
            "_parent" => null,
            "_level" => 1,
            "_is_leaf" => false
        ),

        '172' => array (
            "desc" => "sub array",
            "_id" => 172,
            "_parent" => 163,
            "_level" => 2,
            "_is_leaf" => false
        ),
    )
```

my expected output is

> ```
> Master array
> sub array 172
> sub array from 172
> sub array 200
> sub array from 200
> ```

i tried to use `usort()` like this

```
function sorting($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['_parent']==$b['_parent']) {
        return $a['_level'] - $b['_level'];
    }
    return $a['_id'] - $b['_id'];
}
```

but i still not give my expected output, can anyone give me this suggestion?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to _actually_ post your expected output. Please add it.

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: Could you show us what output you're getting?

Comment: master output, sub array from 172, sub array from 200, sub array 172, sub array 200 @ErtySeidohl

Comment: How are you calling usort? Could you show that code?